# REST where should end point go?

Tags: rest, api-design

Suppose there's USERS and ORDERS

for a specific user's order list

You could do

- `/user/3/order_list`
- `/order/?user=3`

Which one is prefered and why?

Answer (score 1):

Optional parameters tend to be easier to put in the query string.

If you want to return a 404 error when the parameter value does not correspond to an existing resource then I would tend towards a path segment parameter. e.g. /customer/232 where 232 is not a valid customer id.

If however you want to return an empty list then when the parameter is not found then query string parameters. e.g. /contacts?name=dave

If a parameter affects an entire URI structure then use a path e.g. a language parameter  /en/document/foo.txt versus /document/foo.txt?language=en

If unique identifiers to be in a path rather than a query parameter.

Path is friendly for search engine/browser history/ Navigation.

Answer (score 0):

When I started to create an API, I was thinking about the same question.
[Video from apigee](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QpAhXa12xvU&t=1350s). help me a lot.

In a nutshell when you decide to build an API, you should decide which entity is independent and which is only related to someone.
For example, if you have a specific endpoint for orders with create/update/delete operations, then it will be fine to use a second approach `/order/?user=3`.
In the other way, if orders have only one representation, depends on a user and they don't have any special interaction then you could first approach.

[There is also nice article about best practice](http://www.vinaysahni.com/best-practices-for-a-pragmatic-restful-api#limiting-fields)

Answer (score 0):

The whole point of REST is resources. You should try and map them as closely as possible to the actual requests you're going to get. I'd definitely not call it `order_list` because that looks like an action (you're "listing" the orders, while `GET` should be enough to tell you that you're getting something)

So, first of all I think you should have `/users` instead of `/user`, Then consider it as a tree structure:

- A seller (for lack of a better name) can have multiple users
- A user can have multiple orders
- An order can have multiple items

So, I'd go for something like:

- The seller can see its users with `yourdomain.com/my/users`
- The details of a single user can be seen with `yourdomain.com/my/users/3`
- The orders  of a single user can be seen with `yourdomain.com/my/users/3/orders`
- The items of a single order can be seen with `yourdomain.com/my/users/3/orders/5`